# on AWS EC2 instance executable php is not found in /opt/php/php-5.6

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, httpd.conf

I have an ec2 instance provided by my organisation and I see PHP is in /opt/php/php-5.6. There is no PHP executable/binary in /usr/bin folder.

also I see 2 httpd on the machine. /opt/apache/httpd/bin  and /etc/httpd. If I check the status - /usr/sbin/httpd is running it says. I am not getting which httpd is now running.

Please help me how to run a PHP script in this set up and also how to know which httpd is running

Comment: what is the output of `whereis php` ?

Comment: @Haris it is `php: /etc/php.d /etc/php.ini`